# I have error when i want to view profile of users ,it only view the email and does not view on password ,phone

Tags: android, firebase

I want to make an activity that will view the profile of users, but the problem is only email information is the view, phone no, name and password cannot be view and shows. Firebase data not showing in my activity in the android studio

The error is  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziy@2a5f312c`

I tried searching the error that I get, but still cannot find the solution

this is the error when I run the apps

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zziy@363479c4
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1105)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1873)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:562)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzik.disconnect(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzik.zzcv(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzik.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzil.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzeq.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzgm.run(Unknown Source)
04-05 00:22:29.039 20832-21174/? D/SystemUi_TrafficStatsHelper: ifaceNames[0]:wlan0
04-05 00:22:29.039 20832-21174/? D/SystemUi_TrafficStatsHelper: ifaceNames[1]:rmnet_data0
04-05 00:22:29.039 20832-21174/? D/SystemUi_TrafficStatsHelper: ifaceNames[2]:lo
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if theres were some code but you can try this:

> Problem was, that disconnectFromService() function was called from
>   finish() and from onStop() too. So it was called twice, when activity
>   was about to close.
>
> After removing call from onStop(), the exception is thrown no more.

or you can try this one:

Add below line in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="you_package_name:your_service_name"/>
```

or

```
<service android:name="you_package_name:SturkoPlayerService" />
```

from here: [Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409135/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-not-registered)

tell me if you solved your problem!